# How to design content repository in Liferay for access by remote application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, content-management-system, liferay

I have two separate Java applications A and B running on different physical servers.

On  application A (based on Spring Boot framework ) end users view images and image meta data (over 50k images) and has search functionality including faceted search and will use elasticsearch for this. In this application what is the best way to design the content repository ( storage of images and meta data) such that all images can be cached in memory for high performance access?

Application B:
This is liferay 7 based portal.
Authors uploads images and enter meta data about images (or blogs) such as image description Admin approves/publishes the images. These published images are immediately seen in application A. How Liferay can store images to make it possible? Note that application A cannot use Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question:

Liferay has an API, that you can use to interface with the rest of the world - e.g. even event based: When an image is approved, do something. 
Also, images stored in Liferay have a URL - no need to store them somewhere else, you just need to refer to their URL to access them. I'm not sure if that counts as "Application A uses Liferay", you can judge that.

The first part of your question, "what is the best way to design the content repository?": IMHO that part of the question is far out of scope for stackoverflow.com as there tends to be no "correct" answer, but just personal opinions. There's *by far* not enough information to come up with a proper answer on this topic.